# error: package com.google.gson.annotations does not exist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gson

I have gone through many answers but i am unable to resolve the error .
I have added the gson 2.2.4 library.My App gradle is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWwNU.png).

[image: This is my build,.gradle]

Comment: Add this in your gradle section  `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4` .Then `Clean-Rebuild` and `gradle`

Comment: Add compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' in ur build.gradle and sync project.

Comment: show your gradle as you are using retrofit gson will imported automatically if you use proper dependency

Comment: in which gradle section should i add bcz there are many section in build.gradle@IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 2):

In your gradle file, if you add the below line please delete it :

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
}`

Comment: somehow it also was inside my grandle file in `react-native` project